# Is it the best way to compare python objects

Tags: python

Considering these classes

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner
        self.a = None
        self.b = []

object = Foo(mike)
```

each hour, i need to check if Foo is updated (object.a or object.b has changed)
How can i do ?

Do i need to create a new object object2=Foo(mike) and parse attribute to compare with object, put the difference into a list or is there a pythonic way to do it ?

If a create two objects, parse them to build 2 lists and compare them is a good idea ?

Comment: What does "changed" mean? Instance variable changed?

Comment: How is `Foo` updated?

Comment: if at least one object attributes has it value updated. Element added or remove in object.b list etc.
Foo is updated by differents functions.

Comment: Different functions in different threads?

Comment: Who will be update your `Foo` instance? Your code?

Comment: same thread right now

Comment: it's my code yeah, in a while

Comment: Then you have to control updating instance attributes inside class. You shall get updates immediately. Is this ok for you?

Comment: that's what i already to. I have all added itemps but not deleted. if something is in object 1 but not in one, i don't got it

Comment: Simply keep a copy (see the `copy` module) of the object and check it against the current state (and make a new copy if it changed, of course)...

Comment: tune up your code: missing quotes around 'mike', using the reserved work 'object' as variable name...

Comment: what an unnecessary comment Don. Congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem, do not allow anything to change attributes directly.
Use methods instead (e.g. add_b(self, value), set_a(self, value)) in which you can keep control on what's happening.

Try using [properties](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property).

E.g.

```
class Foo(object):
    __owner = None
    __changed = False

    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        old_owner = self.__owner
        if owner != old_owner:
            self.__changed = True
        self.__owner = owner

    owner = property(get_owner, set_owner)

    @property
    def changed(self):
        return self.__changed   

f = Foo('bar')
print f.owner   # bar
f.owner = 'bar2'
print f.owner # bar2
print f.changed # True
```